# Sorting mongodb by reddit ranking algorithm

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

Here is a js code to rank items according to Reddit's ranking algorithm.

My question is: how do I use this code to rank my mongodb documents ?

([Reddit's ranking algorithm](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588))

```
function hot(ups,downs,date){
    var score = ups - downs;
    var order = log10(Math.max(Math.abs(score), 1));
    var sign = score>0 ? 1 : score<0 ? -1 : 0;
    var seconds = epochSeconds(date) - 1134028003;
    var product = order + sign * seconds / 45000;
    return Math.round(product*10000000)/10000000;
}
function log10(val){
  return Math.log(val) / Math.LN10;
}
function epochSeconds(d){
    return (d.getTime() - new Date(1970,1,1).getTime())/1000;
}
```

Comment: Yay, thanks for posting that code!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you can use mapReduce:

```js
var mapper = function() {

    function hot(ups,downs,date){
        var score = ups - downs;
        var order = log10(Math.max(Math.abs(score), 1));
        var sign = score>0 ? 1 : score<0 ? -1 : 0;
        var seconds = epochSeconds(date) - 1134028003;
        var product = order + sign * seconds / 45000;
        return Math.round(product*10000000)/10000000;
    }

   function log10(val){
      return Math.log(val) / Math.LN10;
   }

   function epochSeconds(d){
       return (d.getTime() - new Date(1970,1,1).getTime())/1000;
   }

   emit( hot(this.ups, this.downs, this.date), this );

};
```

And the run the mapReduce (without a reducer):

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    function(){},
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

And of course presuming that your "collection" has the fields for `ups`, `downs` and `date`. Of course the "rankings" need to be emitted in a way that is "unique" otherwise you need a "reducer" to sort out the results.

But generally speaking that should do the job.

Comment: What is "inline"? Can you include the reducer function?

Answer (score 3):

Theres a problem with your function:

```
new Date(1970, 1, 1) // Sun Feb 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
```

Yep, month 1 is *February*, and it uses the systems *timezone* as well.
Epoch in JavaScript is

```
var epoch = new Date(Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1))
```

Since

```
epoch.getTime() // 0
```

The function

```
function epochSeconds(d){
    return (d.getTime() - new Date(1970,1,1).getTime())/1000;
}
```

should be just

```
function epochSeconds(d){
    return d.getTime()/1000;
}
```

Compressing a bit, this returns exactly the same results as the python function in http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588

```
function hot (ups, downs, date){
  var score = ups - downs;
  var order = Math.log(Math.max(Math.abs(score), 1)) / Math.LN10;
  var sign = score > 0 ? 1 : score < 0 ? -1 : 0;
  var seconds = (date.getTime()/1000) - 1134028003;
  var product = order + sign * seconds / 45000;
  return Math.round(product*10000000)/10000000;
}
```