# Batch processing/updating Monogdb documents in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, batch-processing

I would like to process/update every document in a Mongodb collection periodically (every 5 mins or so) and save the results back to the DB. The update function requires actual code to execute on each document (as far as I know) because it needs to perform computations such as taking the difference in timestamps and taking exponents with `Math.pow`, which the [standard MongoDB update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) do not cover.

What is the best way to do this in NodeJS?

---

**Full context:** I am trying to implement the [Hacker News ranking algorithm](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=231209), which is time-dependent. The [discussion I've seen around this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2745805) involves using a separate thread/process to periodically update the scores on documents.

Answer (score 2):

without wasting back and forth investigation it seems you have fields that i will call `points`, time of initial creation `created_date` and, then the ycombinator `result` of `(p - 1) / (t + 2)^1.5`

the easiest is to write a very simple 3 liner [mongo shell script](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/).

```
db.ycombinator.find().forEach(function(doc) {
   var diff = ISODate() - doc.created_date; // subtract date using some form of date ISODate is available in mongo shell
   var hours = diff.tomagicalhours(); // some regulr javascript
   var result = (doc.points - 1) / Math.pow((hours + 2), 1.5); // perform yc algo
   db.ycombinator.update({"_id":doc._id}, {$set:{"result": result} }); // write back into same collection and field, result
})
```

that goes into a file `ycombinator_update.js` and then do a 5 minute crontab.

```
*/5 * * * * mongo ycombinator_update.js
```

the performance of your reads will be noticeably slower during the writes operation contingent on the number of records in that collection.

Comment: this strips you of the need for node.js, mongoose and other mediators.

Comment: try using `node-cron` https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron it will keep everything inside your node app

Comment: this is a mongo shell script. and at time of writing cannot easily import any external libs like moment,node-cron or any conveniences. yes, you could write a node script (and it might even be better) and the above code would drop inside of it.

Comment: What is the performance difference for Mongo shell script vs NodeJS driver?

Comment: the python async mongo driver was a significant 10x higher req/sec over the sync one, but thats multiple read operations (find vs update). i'm fairly confident the mongo shell does not use an async driver.

Answer (score 1):

you could assign scores based on the document timestamp at lookup time, and only keep the raw timestamps in the database.  Since the score is a function of the timestamp anyway, the scoring algorithm can incorporate the exponential decay logic on the unmodified data.  Scores can be converted to timestamps if to search by score.

Comment: This would work great when looking up a single post or a group sorted by some other factor (since I would already know which posts I am looking up), but what I really want is to query for "top" posts sorted via the score. In order to do this I would need to run the "calcScore()" operation over the entire collection before I could query against it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that isn't represented here is the **MongoDB [MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728668/sorting-mongodb-by-reddit-ranking-algorithm) or [Aggregation frameworks](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)**.

Both these frameworks provide a way to iterate over all elements in a collection and output some results into a different collection. The aggregation API does not directly include the primitives we need to calculate the 1.5 exponent in the HN algorithm (no `$sqrt` or `$pow`), but [there is a workaround](http://ilearnasigoalong.blogspot.com/2014/05/the-case-of-missing-operator-how-to-use.html).

I'm not certain at this point which approach is the most performant for this use case (and how it compares to the MongoDB shell script [suggested by Gabe Rainbow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27241235/2359478)).

I believe the next step is to run the update operations in a separate process, which is either scheduled with something like `cron`, or it could be kicked off via the node app itself using `fork` with the following logic:

```
On request for front page:
    # when did we last update the scores for the front page?
    if last_update was within last X minutes:
        return list sorted by score right away
    else
        fork a process to sort the front page
        last_update := Date.Now
        return list sorted by score (either right away [stale], or after the update completes [takes a while])
```