# Sorting records by reddit algorithm using mongodb

Tags: c#, algorithm, mongodb, mapreduce, reddit

I'm trying to implement the reddit algorithm as a sorting option in my app but I'm constantly hitting walls all over the place.

I started my implementation using this ([Sorting mongodb by reddit ranking algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728668/sorting-mongodb-by-reddit-ranking-algorithm#)) post as a guide line.

I tried to convert it to c#; below is my attempt at the conversion.

```
var map = new BsonJavaScript(
    @"function() {

        function hot(score, date){
            var order = log10(Math.max(Math.abs(score), 1));
            var sign = score>0 ? 1 : score<0 ? -1 : 0;
            var seconds = epochSeconds(date) - 1134028003;
            var product = order + sign * seconds / 45000;
            return Math.round(product*10000000)/10000000;
        }

        function log10(val){
            return Math.log(val) / Math.LN10;
        }

        function epochSeconds(d){
            return (d.getTime() - new Date(1970,1,1).getTime())/1000;
        }

        emit( hot(this.VoteCount, this.CreatedAt), this );

    }"
);

var reduce = new BsonJavaScript(
    @"function(){}"
);

var finalize = new BsonJavaScript(
    @"{ 'out': { 'inline': 1 } }"
);

return db.Posts.MapReduce(new MapReduceArgs { MapFunction = map, ReduceFunction = reduce, FinalizeFunction = finalize }).GetResults();
```

He's the results I'm getting from the implementation;

[image]

He's the actual dataset.
[image]

For some reason the function returns 2 objects instead of 4.
Also, what would I need to modify for the function to return the entire post object along with the calculated score?

Would really appreciate it if someone would help me out :)

Thanks in advance,
Jean

Comment: First off: a map reduce...really? Just don't.

Comment: Any suggestions on how you would implement it?

Comment: Probably entirely in C#

Comment: I'll consider that and keep you updated on some benchmarks when I get this to work. :)

Comment: The key thing is not necessarily in the scenario of the lab made benchmark but in how the internal JS engine is called within MongoDB. Especially when you start getting traffic (connections) to this page. The JS engine is simply not designed for this and nor should it be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by making 2 modifications.

These 2 resources where extremely helpful;
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-map-cmd
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce

Firstly I changed what parameters I pass to emit. I'm assigning a "score" value to the post object on the fly and run the hot function on it. Then I pass the key parameter for emit as the object key and the value parameter as the new post object with the score value. **emit(key, value)

```
this.score = hot(this.VoteCount, this.CreatedAt);
emit( this._id, this );
```

Then I changed how I get the results to;

```
db.Posts.MapReduce(new MapReduceArgs { MapFunction = map, ReduceFunction = reduce}).InlineResults
```

Hope this is helpful someone else :)

***I'll post benchmarks using this method of calculating the score to calculating the score in C# when I have some free time.***

---

**Alt implementation / Update:**
I switched to a simpler / faster decay algorithm used by Hacker News as it still meets my requirements. http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574

```
Score = (P-1) / (T+2)^G

where,
P = points of an item (and -1 is to negate submitters vote)
T = time since submission (in hours)
G = Gravity, defaults to 1.8 in news.arc
```