# Meteor - publish a collection sorted on personalized score

Tags: javascript, sorting, meteor, mongodb-query

I want to publish a collection, where documents are scored according to a combination of their fields and the context determined by the user; and the returned result is sorted based on this score, and probably limited to the top results.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093560/meteor-collection-transform-is-it-done-on-the-server-or-on-the-client-or-it-de) shows how to add a `transform` filter on a collection at the moment of the publication. However, I'm not sure `transform` is an efficient approach for computing a field that I want to use in the sort..

Finally, it would be awesome to use Mongo map reduce to quickly return recommended items based on the computed score, which can be done in parallel.

@brett-mclain [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728668/sorting-mongodb-by-reddit-ranking-algorithm) how some map reduce sorting can be done in pure Mongo. There are a few [Meteor](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/blob/master/index.js) packages [out there](https://github.com/hiddenswitch/meteor-mongo-server) to extend Meteor collections, but I could not find how to use them in the Meteor publication (vs in a method) Besides, [here](https://github.com/hiddenswitch/meteor-mongo-server) the map reduce output is send to another collection that is apparently overwritten each time the method is called.

Here is roughly the logic I'd like to achieve:

```
/* Server */
Meteor.publish('getRecommendedItems', function() {
  var u = Users.findOne(this.userId);
  var scoreItem = function(item, u) { ... };
  return Items.find(
    {},
    {
      transformInParallel: function(doc) {
        doc.score = scoreItem(doc);
      },
      sort: {score: -1},
      limit: 10,
    }
  );
});


/* Client template*/
Template.templateName.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe('getRecommendedItems');
  this.items = Items.find({}, sort: {score: -1});
});
```

where I except `score` to be accessible in the client without doing any computation there.

It seems easier to do custom things in `Meteor.methods`, but `Meteor.publish` feels like the natural place to do this; because it's where Meteor's magical reactivity takes place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting mongodb by reddit ranking algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728668/sorting-mongodb-by-reddit-ranking-algorithm)

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate and linked to a stackoverflow question about implementing reddit's time decay algorithm by sorting in MongoDB. Their solution is to use a map reduce: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728668/sorting-mongodb-by-reddit-ranking-algorithm

Comment: That's a very interesting post. I'm wondering how I can do those mongo operations within the Meteor framework. My understanding is that Meteor adds a layer that provides live updates to the client, and apparently restricts the operation one can do to achieve this result. From a Meteor collection, there is noting like `.mapReduce`
Let me know if I'm missing something, else I'll edit and reopen the question

Comment: Your server will stress if you compute in server

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   transformInParallel: function(doc) {
>     doc.score = scoreItem(doc);
>   },
>   sort: {score: -1},
>   limit: 10,
> ```

This will result in a full-database scan.

Time-decay solutions, which are actually common programming test questions, aren't really appropriate for your use case.

If your scale is small, simply precompute a full set of

```
{score: ..., userId: ..., item: ...}
```

documents in a separate collection. The indices for a billion small documents like these will fit entirely in a single database server's RAM; this will be suitable for at most e.g. 30,000 items and 30,000 users.

If your needs exceed this, you have to think about what part of the score calculation can be shared between users. If no part of the calculation can be shared, you should read about how Facebook implements social graphs on conventional databases.